# django model - on_delete=models.PROTECT()

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to use `on_delete` with my models but my IDE is asking me for: collector, fields, sub_objs, using (i.e. `..., on_delete=models.PROTECT(collector, fields, sub_objs, using))`.

Can someone please tell me what these are and give me a quick example because I can find them documented anywhere :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ignore your IDE. It is trying to get you to call the `models.PROTECT` function, which does indeed take those arguments. But you actually want to pass the function itself:

```
my_field = models.ForeignKey(..., on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

ie without the parentheses that would call the function.

(Insert rant about using an IDE with a dynamic language here...)

Comment: any chance of telling how catch the `ProtectedError` in views.py (Should I be using a `try:`?)

Comment: What should I be catching? (sorry about the ignorance, python is not my strong point)

Comment: You should be catching django.db.models.ProtectedError

Answer (score 1):

Import like:(Python 2.7)

```
from django.db.models.deletion import PROTECT
```

Then you can use it directly.

```
category = ForeignKey(TCategory, PROTECT, null=False, blank=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

models.PROTECT prevents deletions but does not raise an error by default.

you can create a custom exception for it, which is already protected.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

class ModelIsProtectedError(IntegrityError):
    pass

def prevent_deletions(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    raise ModelIsProtectedError("This model can not be deleted")


#in your models.py:
pre_delete.connect(prevent_deletions, sender=<your model>)
```

Comment: The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/) state: `Prevent deletion of the referenced object by raising ProtectedError, a subclass of django.db.IntegrityError`